# Yet another endless page dilemma

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery, pagination

I am trying to implement an endless page setup for my page. I've been trying a lot of different methods for two days now but can't seem to get it to work. I liked the proposed setup from this blogpost but I can't seem to get it to work: http://pedromtavares.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/endless-page-scrolling-with-rails-3-and-jquery/

I also tried Ryan Bates screencast but didn't manage to implement it...

I tried the following:

Installed plugin

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/pedromtavares/endless_scroll_example.git
```

Modified my controller home:

```
def index

last = params[:last].blank? ? Time.now + 1.second : Time.parse(params[:last])
@feeds = Feed.input(last)

end
```

Modified my "Feed-model" with the new method 'input':

```
def self.input(last)
   self.where("created_at < ? ", last).order('created_at desc').limit(5)
end
```

Modified my index

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'endless' %>
<% end %>


<%unless @feeds.blank?%>
<ul class='list' last="<%=@feeds.to_a.last.created_at%>">
<%= render :partial => 'feeds', :collection => @feeds%>

<div id='infinite-scroll'></div>
</ul>
<%end%>
```

My partial _feeds.html.erb looks like this (just filling out text :):

```
<%=feeds.title%>
jfjh
</p>
<p>
    jfjh
    </p>
    <p>
        jfjh
        </p>
        <p>
            jfjh
            </p>
            <p>
                jfjh
                </p>

                 <br>
<hr>
```

Added my new javascript (endless.js) courtesy of pedromtavares

```
$('ul').endlessScroll({
  fireOnce: true,
  fireDelay: 500,
    ceaseFire: function(){
      return $('#infinite-scroll').length ? false : true;
    },
    callback: function(){
      $.ajax({
          url: '/home',
          data: {
              last: $(this).attr('last')
          },
          dataType: 'script'
        });
    }
});
```

My final javascript file looks like this:

```
<% unless @feeds.blank? %>
    $('.endless_scroll_inner_wrap').append("<%=escape_javascript(render :partial => 'feeds', :collection => @feeds)%>");
    $('ul').attr('last', '<%=@feeds.to_a.last.created_at%>')
<% else %>
    $('#infinite-scroll').detach();
<% end %>
```

I don't get any errors but no infinite scroll either. I get the first posts from the array but not the rest. Can't figure out what I am doing wrong and it feels like I've tried everything by now... Please help!

Comment: https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/wiki/How-To:-Create-Infinite-Scrolling-with-jQuery

Comment: already tried that solution but I could not make it work either... Dunno if my app is missing some javascript plugin or something....

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem myself.  My issue was that my append in my javascript could not find the proper div.  Might work for you -

In your javascript file, change:

```
    $('.endless_scroll_inner_wrap').append...
```

to:

```
    $('#infinite-scroll').append...
```

and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks but it turened out that I had some jQuery issue that prohibited me to do what I wanted to.